# Re-arranging array keys in multiple dimension array [PHP]

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

Hoping you can help.
I am currently building a CMS and trying to be clever where by any pages that requires a list view type of of look and feel can be reuseable.
The page (controller) that calls this list view html code will basically prepare the data that is required but I am falling over now where the data I get back from the database, I want to re-arrange the array key.
So for example, say my query returned firstname, lastname, email, pkey, createdate currently my code would display it in that order but I want to see if there is a way where I can re-arrange them keys to say be like 
pkey, email, firstname, lastname, createdate.

Dont get me wrong, I could break down the sql query and define the order then but was thinking if there was something via PHP that could work on multiple dimensional arrays?

thanks in advance

Raj

Comment: Why does the order of the array keys matter? You don't have to display them in the same order they're in the array.

Comment: Sounds like a case for [uksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) batman!

Comment: idea behind what I am trying to do is that this html page that lists the rows will be a universal page that i can reuse as long as the data given is correct. So 1 controller might be get all the users, another be get all the products but say if I do an inner join etc, i would want to sort my data from controller level before I pass over to the html list page

Comment: like I say, I am trying to be clever to see if its possible else I will rethink how I can play it

Comment: why the down votes btw - not relevant or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a case for [uksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) batman!

```
$data = [
    'firstname' => 'Mark',
    'lastname' => 'Baker',
    'email' => 'mymailbox@mydomain.com',
    'pkey' => 'private',
    'createdate' => '2015-12-19',
];

$order = ['pkey', 'email', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'createdate'];

uksort(
    $data,
    function($a, $b) use ($order) {
        return array_search($a, $order) > array_search($b, $order);
    }
);
var_dump($data);
```

**EDIT**

If you have a multi-dimensional array then use array_walk to loop through the top-level, using this code logic as your callback:

```
$order = ['pkey', 'email', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'createdate'];
array_walk(
    $myGiantArrayOfAllUsers,
    function(&$data) use ($order) {
        uksort(
            $data,
            function($a, $b) use ($order) {
                return array_search($a, $order) > array_search($b, $order);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Or simply use my previous code as you're foreaching over the array elements at the point where you display them

Comment: Ive got the single array version like you stated above working, but I need it for a multi dimension array dude

Comment: Thanks Mark - appreciate the skillz